# Permission For READ_PHONE_STATE Appcelerator android 6.0

Tags: javascript, permissions, titanium, appcelerator, imei

i have a probleme in android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE i deploy my project to samsung galaxy S6 i use this code to request the READ_PHONE_STATE permission 
but it's not working ,i use the ti.permissions module .

in my tiapp.xml i added

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

but it's not working because im using an android 6.0

1. First i check if i have already the permission
2. If not i request it
3. if the request is successfull i do the work normaly
4. if not i just alert an error (for now )

   ```
       var imeimodule=require("com.imei");
               var imei;
            var permissions = require("ti.permissions");

   try {

             if (  !permissions.hasPermission('android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'))
             {
                   alert('here');

       permissions.requestPermissions(['android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'],function(e) { 
           if (e.success != 0)
           {    
                Ti.API.debug("Permissions OK");
                imei = imeimodule.example(); 
                Ti.App.Properties.setString('EMEI',imei);
            }
           else
           {
               Ti.API.warn("Permissions denied"); 
           }
       });

            }
             else alert ('ok cool');
   ```

   }

   catch (e){
                   alert(e.message);
                }

Comment: Really need to provide more details. 'Not working' isn't helpful enough. Are you getting an error, what is the error, is it simply failing with no error?

Comment: as you can see the 'here' alert is shown , and in the 'if e.seccess !=0' i wrote an alert and in 'else' i did another alert but neither are shown , so  
imei = imeimodule.example();  is not executed and my app depends on this 'imei'

Answer (score 0):

you can try this module 
https://github.com/gimdongwoo/Ti-Android-RequestStoragePermission
use it after window open

Comment: I dont have a probleme with the Storage permission , i have a problème with the " READ_PHONE_STATE " , are they the same ?